# postgres: Search for multiple words in string

Tags: postgresql

I'm implementing a rudimentary form of search for my company backoffice system. I would like to find all products names that contain all words in a search query.

So if I have these two products:

- `Deodorant with cucumber flavor`
- `Deoderant with apple flavor`

the search query: `cucumber deoderant` should match only `Deoderant with cucumber flavor`.

I can make it work for the query `deoderant cucumber` like so:

```
SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE name ~* regexp_replace('deoderant cucumber', '\s+', '.*', 'g');
```

but this approach does not work when the order is not the name in the query and the product name.

I know that this is possible by doing something like

```
SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE name ~* 'deoderant' AND name ~* cucumber';
```

but I would ideally like to stay away from string interpolation as it becomes a bit messy in my current environment.

Is there another, more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the value into an array and then use the ["contains"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator `@>` with the words you are looking for:

```
SELECT product_name 
FROM products 
WHERE regexp_split_to_array(lower(name), '\s+') @> array['deodorant', 'cucumber'];
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GNL7374

Comment: This only works for whole-word matches. Apparentl it's good enough for the original poster, but is there anything for general substring matches?